# How to pass react state to Node backend?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to build a weather app using Node + React. The weather API is fetched in Node using this code:

```
const apiUrl = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&appid=${process.env.REACT_APP_WEATHER_API_KEY};
axios.get(apiUrl)
    .then(response => { res.json(response.data) })
    .catch(error => {
        res.redirect('/error');
        console.log(error);
    });
```

As you can see the `latitude` and `longitude` are variables. Now I have acquired the geo coordinates in my React app from user input and stored in a state:

```
this.setState({
    coordinate: [response.result.latitude, response.result.longitude];
});
```

The question is, how can I pass the state to my Node code so `lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}` could receive the geo coordinates?

Comment: You need to create an api endpoint on your node application which accepts latitude and longitude and makes the api call to weather api. In react, call the node api endpoint with latitude and longitude as params. It should be a post call.

Comment: @Deepak can you post an answer with an example please?

Comment: 1. For making api calls from react: https://pusher.com/tutorials/consume-restful-api-react 2. Other ways for fetch and post api calll: https://malcoded.com/posts/react-http-requests-axios/ 3. Sample for creating nodejs api endpoints: https://www.toptal.com/nodejs/secure-rest-api-in-nodejs. I am sorry, I will  try to create sample application when I get time. I hope the above links help.